# Add DateTime + Integer in a DQL query

Tags: datetime, symfony, doctrine

I want to retrive Event which are not yet finished. 
My problem is that **startTime** is a **DateTime** and **duration** is an **Integer**.

How can I make this addition ?

This code :

```
$events = $this->getRepository('Event')->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->where('e.startTime+e.duration > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')
               ->getQuery();
               ->getResult();
```

throw me :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an integer to a date. How should PHP/Doctrine interpret the integer ? days, hours, minutes, ... ?

MySQl provides some functions to handle DATE and TIME, and some of them are available in DQL language, such as DATE_ADD which is what you need if your integer is a days amount ! Look at [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)

And if your integer is a seconds amount, it's not implemented in DQL so you need to create a "native SQL query" and use MySQL functions such as [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html#id694089)

And if you'd like to create a TIME_ADD function for DQL, you read this article that explains [how to create your own DQL functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) !

Comment: thx. Yes my integer is in seconds, that's why DATE_ADD() won't work for me :(. And my laziness hope there is another way than native SQL

Comment: I've already encountered this issue, and I wrote native SQL... :D